# C# getting values from DataTable or BindingSource

Tags: c#, binding, datatable, datarow, bindingsource

I have a labels that need values retreieved from a Database.

I am able to query the database but how can I extract values from a DataTable and place them in the appropiate labels

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DataTable you have rows and columns. To select a particular cell you need to do this:

```
label1.Text = dataTable[0][0];
```

This will set the label1 text to Row 0, Column 0 value.

To iterate through each row use:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
Console.WriteLine(row["ColumnName1"]);
Console.WriteLine(row["ColumnName2"]);
Console.WriteLine(row["ColumnName3"]);
Console.WriteLine(row["ColumnName4"]);
}
```

This will print values for columns against each row. In this code you need to replace string for columnname (e.g. ColumnName1) with your column names

Answer (score 1):

Example of how you retrieve a value from the first row and the column named "MyFirstColumn":

```
label1.Text = myDataTable.Rows[0]["MyFirstColumn"]
```